# Rails 7: Skip validation when retrieving a recond

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Im working on a project and im stuck on this logic:

I have for example

**Table Users**:

- id
- name
- last_name
- phone
- email

**Table Clubs**:

- id
- name
- ref_code
- city
- postal
- address
- user_id

**Model User**:

has_many :clubs

**Model Club**:

belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy

validates :name, :ref_code, :city, :postal, :address, presence: true

A user is logged in with devise:

**On page1** -> i create a first instance of a club with only a value for ref_code:

@club = current_user.clubs.first_or_initialize

@club.asign_attributes(ref_code: %user's entry from the form%)

@user.save(validate: false) # to skip presence validation

**On page2** -> I have a form for the user to enter the rest of the club info

@club = current_user.clubs.first_or_initialize (which retrieves the club created in page1)

...

```
<%= form_with(model:@club, url: some_path, method: :put) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>
<%= f.text_field :city, required: true %>
<%= f.text_field :postal, required: true %>
<%= f.text_field :address, required: true %>
<% end %>
```

The form shows the missing fields with errors (is-invalid class) which i dont want in this case.

Is there a way to skip those validations for this specific page2 when @user is retrieved ?

Comment: How about not sending data every time to the backend? I mean store data in the frontend for both pages and send them to the backend only when page2 is completed.

Comment: The only way for the errors to be displayed is if the object has been validated, which Rails doesn't do in a `first_or_initialize` - so this validation is happening in code that you're not showing us.

Comment: Are you using `required` field tags on the form fields that are rendering errors?

Comment: I elaborated a bit more to give a clearer idea of what and where im stuck.
With or without required: true I get the same undesired outcome.